# hey I just need to know how to calculate e^x=363. thanks

Tags: logarithm

I am having problems as I can't find any site out there that can help me find the solution of the equation $e^x=\,363.$ How does one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unknown exponent is a *logarithm*. As the base is $e$, it means the *natural* logarithm. So

$$x = \ln 363 \approx 5.894.$$